# How to Set Auth Module in Bokeh Server

Tags: python, bokeh, tornado

I'm running a Bokeh app as shown in [standalone_embed.py](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py) and want to use an authentication hook with it, as shown [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/howto/server_auth). How do I set the `auth_module` in `bokeh.settings.settings` in `standalone_embed.py`?

I tried

```
from bokeh.settings import settings

settings.auth_module = "auth.py"
settings.xsrf_cookies = True
```

but that doesn't seem to do anything. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

`Server` can take the authentication module as param as follows:

```
auth_module_path = <path to auth.py>
if auth_module_path:
    server_kwargs['auth_provider'] = AuthModule(auth_module_path)

server = Server(
    bokeh_applications,  # list of Bokeh applications
    io_loop=loop,        # Tornado IOLoop
    **server_kwargs      # port, num_procs, etc.
)
```